# Why is height of ListItem (a LinearLayout) so tall when layout_height is changed to wrap_content?

Tags: android, android-layout, listview, textview, android-button

I have a pretty simple layout (Linear) for my ListView item, just 3 widgets laid out horizontally: 2 TextView items then a Button.  But even though the layout_height of all 3 is wrap_content it seems that that value used for the button forces the ListItem to expand a lot more than needed.  But simply changing the value of the layout_height to 25dp eliminates this.

Why is the Button's wrap_content having this effect, and how to stop it?

Notice the background colors in my screenshots below, showing widget dimensions.  The *only* difference between the two pics is that in my XML (at bottom) the layout_height of the Button has been changed from wrap_content to 25dp.

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8"?>
<LinearLayout xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
    android:layout_width="match_parent"
    android:layout_height="wrap_content"
    android:orientation="horizontal"
    >

    <TextView
        android:id="@+id/tvTotal"
        android:layout_width="0dp"
        android:layout_height="wrap_content"
        android:gravity="left"
        android:layout_gravity="left"
        android:text="0."
        android:textSize="18sp"
        android:maxLines="1"
        android:layout_weight=".15"
        android:background="@color/LightGreen"
        />

    <TextView
        android:id="@+id/tvName"
        android:layout_width="0dp"
        android:layout_height="wrap_content"
        android:gravity="left"
        android:text=""
        android:textSize="18sp"
        android:maxLines="1"
        android:layout_weight=".55"
        android:background="@color/LightBlue"
        />

    <Button
        android:id="@+id/btnMyButton"
        android:layout_width="0dp"
        android:layout_height="25dp"
        android:gravity="right"
        android:layout_gravity="right"
        android:textColor="@color/CornflowerBlue"
        android:text="Questions"
        android:textSize="16dp"
        android:maxLines="1"
        android:layout_weight=".3"
        android:background="@color/black"
        >
    </Button>

</LinearLayout>
```

Using wrap_content for Button's layout_height:

[image]

Hardcoding 25dp for Button's layout_height:

[image]

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The extra space are buttons default padding.

If you want to remove it use:

```
android:minHeight="0dp"
android:minWidth="0dp"
```

in your code

```
 <Button
    android:id="@+id/btnMyButton"
    android:layout_width="0dp"
    android:layout_height="wrap_content"
    android:layout_gravity="right"
    android:layout_weight=".3"
    android:background="@color/black"
    android:gravity="right"
    android:maxLines="1"
    android:minHeight="0dp"
    android:minWidth="0dp"
    android:text="Questions"
    android:textColor="@color/CornflowerBlue"
    android:textSize="16dp"></Button>
```

Comment: Sure enough.  Bizarre.  Why would Android jack in so much padding, and also why on the Button but not other widgets?

Comment: because of the Ux issue i guess . cause button are designed to be clickable..and visible text inside them..so the default padding are added.

Comment: That was a lot of default padding.